# Increase UIButton Tap Area without Stretching Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom button with an image that is small (10x10). I need to increases the tap area of this button without stretching the size of the image.

Setting the content mode to scaleAspectFit stretches the image.
Changing the content insets stretches the image.

Everything I try stretches the image when I increase the size of the button.

EDIT: The image is set as the button's image and not the background image

EDIT: Here is more explanation with screenshots.

[image: select 10x10]

^ Here I have selected the button that has an image 10x10 in size

[image: selected image stretched]

^ Here I have increased the size of the button, yet the image is now stretched.

Comment: Just place the image of button as front image not background image.

Comment: @vaibhav It is not set as the background image

Comment: can you explain more with screenshot, what you exact need ..

Comment: @vaibhav Please check updated question. Thank you.

Comment: OK i see the update, I don't know how you are placing image on button but if you place the image as image not background it will not increase till its original size, just increase your image size to 32x32 instead of 10x10 its too small to place.

Answer (score 1):

As @vaibhav has added in comment : Set Button image in image option not in background option :

[image]

After that if you will increase the size of the button the image will not stretch.

Refer these below images :

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see the image size is 20 and the button frame is 50.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But again, my button image is set as an image not as the background. Please check my updated question for screenshots. My 10x10 image is still being stretched. It stops stretching after it gets around 20x20 though.

Comment: If the image would have stretched , It would have stretched to the actual size of the button. The image expands to its actual size if gets space. Please check your image size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the `contentmode` of your button's imageView to `.center`

```
your_button.imageView?.contentMode = .center
```

and set your button's image by

```
your_button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Document

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624033-imageview?changes=_4

Comment: This still stretches the button image for me.